# How to insert data from the frontend in custom field wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, codex

I'm working on insert data from frontend form in a custom post type
I created the post type with the taxonomy in function.php file and it was added successfully in my Dashbord
and now I want to get the data from the front end and insert it the custom post type created
this the code in myTemplate.php

```php
<?php
$posting = date("y") . date("m") ."-". date("h") . date("i");

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    
    $form_weeding = array(
   'form-title' => $_POST['title_cover'], 
   'from-description' => $_POST['description_cover'],
    );
    
    $weeding_id= wp_insert_post($form_weeding, true);
    
    add_post_meta($weeding_id, 'title_cover', $_POST['title_cover'], true);
    add_post_meta($weeding_id, 'description_cover', $_POST['description_cover'], true);
    
    update_field('title_cover',  $_POST['title_cover'],$weeding_id);
    //update_field('description_cover',  $_POST['description_cover'],$weeding_id);
    
}

 ?>

    <form action="" method="POST" class="form wpwd-form init" enctype="multipart/form-data">
             
            <div class="content-flex form-div">
                <input type="text" id = "title1" placeholder="<?php esc_html_e( 'Tap your Title Here*' ) ?>" name="title_cover" class="content-margin" nrequired>

            </div>
            
            <div  class="form-div">
                <textarea id="textarea-cover" name="description_cover" rows="5" cols="33" placeholder="<?php esc_html_e( 'Tape your paragraph Here*' ) ?>"></textarea>

            </div>
            <div class="form-div">
               <button type="submit" id="boutton-form" name="submit">Publish</button> 
            </div>

</form>
```

but I blocked here I don't how to insert the data in my post type.
if any one here can help me I will be thankful
thank you in advance

Comment: First thing that is wrong is that you're trying to insert unsanitized data into the database

Comment: @HowardE  thankyou ,you are right , I already  encoded the form in my original code  , I edit the code now in the this post.

Comment: You need to add your 'post_type' in the argument. What is the name of your post type?